# waitForFunction will fail if element handle is passed and context is destroyed

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

If I pass in an element handle, in the case `body`, as an argument o a waitForFunction, and then the context is destroyed (due to navigation), that promise will fail.

I can't improve the code inside the `waitForFunction` because the fail happens on puppeteer's side.

Is there nay wait to make this code work without adding a `catch`?

```js
it('should survive navigations with handles', async({page, server}) => {
  await page.goto(server.EMPTY_PAGE);
  const body = await page.$('BODY');
  const watchdog = page.waitForFunction(el => !node.isConnected, {}, body);
  await page.goto(server.PREFIX + '/consolelog.html');
  await watchdog;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is adding some boilerplate. Running a function to declare a variable with that element and then check for that variable.

```js
fit('should survive navigations with handles', async({page, server}) => {
  await page.goto(server.EMPTY_PAGE);
  await page.evaluate(() => {
    window.__node = document.querySelector('BODY');
  });
  const watchdog = page.waitForFunction(() => !(window.__node && window.__node.isConnected));
  await page.goto(server.PREFIX + '/consolelog.html');
  await watchdog;
});
```